# How to get the value of non public member

Tags: c#, .net

How to get the value of non public member of the OPCGroup using OPCDA.NET in C#

```
private void DataChangeHandler(object sender, DataChangeEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       object obj = sender;
       OpcGroup grp = (OpcGroup)sender; // I want the OPCgroup non public member value

       if (InvokeRequired)
       {
           BeginInvoke(new DataChangeEventHandler(DataChangeHandler), 
                       new object[] { sender, e });
           //return;
       }
       if (parameter.X == 0)
       {
           parameter.X = 1;
           Thread th = new Thread(param.update);
           th.Start(e);
       }
   }
   catch(OPCException ) { }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't try to use non-public members. If the author of the code has hidden it, you should assume that:

- They don't want you to access it, at least not directly.
- The implementation could change at any time, and your code should keep working.

You *can* use reflection to access non-public members (assuming appropriate permissions at execution time) but I would highly discourage you from doing so if possible.