# Why is "_validated " field hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got badly stuck with duplicate validation call when working with recaptcha on one of my ASP.NET forms, problem was logically there was no way to make sure `Page.Validate()` is called and called only once, recaptcha returns false if `Page.IsValid` is called without `Page.Validate()` and there is no Property on `Page` or `Control` to find out if `Validate()` is called.

I found a workaround for it: [How to determine whether page was validated?](http://forums.asp.net/post/1527065.aspx), but I believe this is an important property and should be available.

Any thoughts why this Property is not made available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question I'll forward you to the excellent answer on a similar question: [get the value of non public member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816870/get-the-value-of-non-public-member/5816909#5816909).

But if you think this is *really* important property, you could implement your own `Validated`  and bind your validation logic to it. E.g. you could override both `Validate` methods in the `Page` class for this:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public bool Validated { get; private set; }

    public override void Validate(string validationGroup)
    {
        this.Validated = true;
        base.Validate(validationGroup);
    }

    public override void Validate()
    {
        this.Validated = true;
        base.Validate();
    }
}
```