# Unable to cast Generic record to object

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

Hi I have below model in c#. These are Avro files.

```cs
public ProductMessageEvents GetValue(TestPayload parameter)
{
    return new ProductMessageEvents()
        {
            Metadata = new KafkaProductEvent.Metadata
                {
                    Timestamp = "test",
                    Environment = "test"
                },
            Product = new KafkaProductEvent.Product
                {
                    AgeGrading = "test",
                    KeycodeType = "type1",
                    FamilyTree = new KafkaProductEvent.FamilyTree
                        {
                            Class = new KafkaProductEvent.CodeNamePair
                                {
                                    Code = "test code",
                                    Name = "test name"
                                }
                        },
                    DssProduct = new KafkaProductEvent.DssProduct
                        {
                            DocumentStatus = "active"
                        }
                      Options = new Option[]
            {
              new Option
              {
                PrimaryColour = new CodeNamePair
                {
                  Name = "White",
                },
                SecondaryColour = new CodeNamePair
                {
                  Name = "red",
                }
              },
              new Option
              {
                PrimaryColour = new CodeNamePair
                {
                  Name = "White",
                }
              },
                },
            Version = "latestVersion"
        };
    }
}
```

If I try to access the below value it works.

```
 object ageGrading = ((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["AgeGrading"];
```

If I try to access the below value, then it throws

```
object familyTree = ((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["FamilyTree"]["Class"]["Code"];
```

It throws error `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object`

[image: Option data]

Can someone help me to identify this error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. It is not working. Thanks

Comment: nobody ever reads exception messages :( _"Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object"_ means that you are trying to apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting this object to a GenericRecord `((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])` but it returns this `((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["FamilyTree"]` as an object.  You'll need to cast each level to GenericRecord to get to it's properties.

```
((GenericRecord)((GenericRecord)((GenericRecord)response.Message.Value["Product"])["FamilyTree"])["Class"])["Code"]
```

Comment: May I know how Can I do at each level?

Comment: Hi, If I have some enumerable data then how we can get data? I have added some code above.

Comment: Cast it to `IEnumerable<Options>` instead.

Comment: I tired to cast. I have attached screen shot. But how can I get non public members? Inside non public members there is content which holds my value.

Comment: I really like this guys answer to that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816870/how-to-get-the-value-of-non-public-member.   If you must do it you'll need to use reflection and that's a whole other ball game.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of manually doing this do we have any library for doing this?

Comment: Google "Access nonpublic member c#" and you'll see suggestions.  As far as I know you are going to have to write code to access the properties you want.